# Why my app supports only 13 devices

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was very confuse, after uploading app to play store.
I saw that my app supports only 13 devises, and all of them are tablet devices.
Could anyone, please, help me?
My AndroidManifest is here:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

<application
    android:name=".activities.base.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.main.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.homescreen.HomescreenActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.camera.CameraActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SWCoinSettingsStyle" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.send.SendActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.receive.ReceiveActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.login.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="name"
        android:value="value" />
</application>
```

Maybe problem is in  libraries that I use?
this is part from my build.gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "id"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.+'
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

//QR
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

//log crash
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Also I have some warning during building apk

> Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
>   with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove below code from `manifest`.

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Also remove below code

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
```

Comment: Thank`s for answer. I try this but result is the same only 13 devices in play store :(

Comment: When I remove this, I got this error during build apk
http://joxi.ru/zAN4qa5UljJ9Bm

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536